# Should I use <h:form> in composite component or not

Tags: forms, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I would like to know whether I should use `<h:form>` tag in a composite component or not?

For example ;

```
<composite:implementation>
    <h:form>
        <h:message for="textPanel" style="color:red;" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="textPanel">
            #{cc.attrs.nameLable} : 
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{cc.attrs.nameValue}" />
            #{cc.attrs.emailLable} : 
            <h:inputText id="email" value="#{cc.attrs.emailValue}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.registerButtonAction}" 
            value="#{cc.attrs.registerButtonText}"
        />
    </h:form>
</composite:implementation>
```

Comment: What is exactely your question/problem? There are lots of tutorials on composite components

Comment: No way! You should not use h:form in composite:component. One form in html is best practice.Multiple form in html cause problem and it is hard to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I too had a same issue, I had included my form inside composite component and that did not work. But once I had taken in out from composite component, it worked like a charm. So my experience is that it would not work if you had included form inside composite component.

PS - This is for primefaces.